# Logging inside Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert this piece of code to Java 8 stream:

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
    Actor actor = null;
    for (Actor actor : list) {
        log.info("Actor being read: "  actor.getCode());
        List<String> areaList = areaDAO.getArea(actor.getCode());
        if (!areaList.isEmpty()) {
            actor.setArea(areaList.get(0));
            log.info("Area{" + areaList.get(0)
                 + "} is fetched for actor{" + actor.getCode() + "}.");
        }
        this.getContext().setReadCount(1);
    }
}
```

However I am not sure how to deal with logging in this case? Is it a good practice? Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: Why are you calling `setReadCount(1)` repeatedly?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams?

Comment: I don’t see your code as the perfect example of where streams are an advantage. Your code is modifying existing `Actor` objects where one ideal of streams is they are side-effect free; yours won’t be. But of course, you can.

Answer (score 45):

Often we put logging into our code to support debugging. In this case I would recommend you to have a look at the [peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) method.

Here is a hint:

```
   List<Actor> actors = ...;

    actors.
        stream().
        peek(a -> System.out.println("Processing code: " + a.getCode())).
        forEach(a -> {/*Do something here*/});
```

From the javadocs:

> API Note:
>       This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline:

Answer (score 4):

I think that using forEach in this case would be working quite nice for you? Example:

```
list.stream().forEach(actor -> {
    log.info(String.format("Actor being read {%s}", actor));
    String actorCode = actor.getCode();
    areaDAO.getArea(actorCode).stream().findFirst().ifPresent(area -> {
       actor.setArea(area);
       log.info(String.format("Area {%s} is fetched for actor {%s}", area, actorCode));
    });
    getContext().setReadCount(1);
})
```

You may want to throw in `Objects.isNull()` as well in some cases - e.g for that getCode part - as well as `Optional.ofNullable`?

Comment: where are you calling setArea? Also do you mean use Optional.ofNullable(actor.getCode())?

Comment: if you just use a stream to do a `.forEach()` on it then please do not use a stream.