# Logging warning message while processing streams in java

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to log error messages if the map `rdsDesksByName.get(e.getKey())` does not have any value for the key.
How can I handle this within streams?

Currently I return `createDeskWithScope(rdsDesksByName.get(e.getKey()),ds.outOfScope())`, but how can I enhance this function to log an error message if `rdsDesksByName` does not have any value for the key, otherwise it should process as usual

```
List<Desk> desks = deskScopesByName.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> {
        return deskScopesByName.get(e.getKey())
            .stream()
            .map(ds -> {
                return createDeskWithScope(rdsDesksByName.get(e.getKey()), ds.outOfScope());
            });                     
    })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Define a method for that `flatMap` block and also possibly for the `map` block within. That way you have better control and ease to understand where to log. A simple question to you, given a block of code without streams, how would have you done that?

Comment: I will simply just add a .peek(a -> System.out.println("")) after stream, you may do a short hand comparison, or even use .filter(), that's it.

Comment: as it misleads `deskScopesByName.get(e.getKey())` could have been `e.getValue()`

Comment: Several duplicates otherwise to look for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555977/logging-the-result-of-filter-while-using-java-streams-filter-by-predicate ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109858/logging-inside-stream/43110075 ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501366/how-to-log-filtered-values-in-java-streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the flatmapping operation, find an object by the key and use the `if-else` condition:

- If the object is `null` (no value for such key), log a message and return `Stream.empty()`.
- Otherwise, continue processing using `createDeskWithScope` method.

Here is how the code might look like (untested, but should give you an idea):

```
List<Desk> desks = deskScopesByName.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Desk rdsDesk = rdsDesksByName.get(key);
        if (rdsDesk == null) {
            log.warn("There is no Desk present for {}", key);
            return Stream.empty();
        } else {
            return entry.getValue()
                .stream()
                .map(ds -> createDeskWithScope(rdsDesk, ds.outOfScope()));
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I recommend wrapping the flatmapping operation inside a method.

Comment: `deskScopesByName.keySet()` and then `deskScopesByName.get(key)` means it was better with `entrySet`.

Comment: besides, better abstraction is when you move those code blocks to a method, which could be `private` if not reusable, improves readability to a great extent. (if you recommend, maybe you should edit the answer as well :))

Comment: You are right Naman, I didn't notice the `deskScopesByName.get(..)` uses the very same Map. Thanks for a note. Regarding to the readability, I agree with a private method.

Comment: @Holger: How would you replace the `rdsDesksByName.get(key)` lookup? It's a completely separate map from the `deskScopesByName` one.

Comment: I’ve been misled by those almost identical names. So, the result of `rdsDesksByName.get(key)` has the same type as the return value of `createDeskWithScope(…)`?

Comment: @Holger: I think it might be anything but my assumption (and the answer acceptance proves) is that: `deskScopesByName` is `Map<String, List<Desk>>` and `rdsDesksByName` is `Map<String, Desk>`. The most important is that `createDeskWithScope(...)` method should return `Desk`. Therefore **yes**, as you said. I know the assumptions are wrong while answering, however, it is the only possible combination I see so far and I felt I could help the OP with my answer. Thanks for the review! (I remove the comments later).